# executing another program from a Java program

Tags: java, exec

Is there any way to execute the .class file of a program from another Java program.

Earlier I used **Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c C:\\file.jar")** where file.jar was created in eclipse using the export option and selecting "Runnable jar" in it. But whenever I try to execute the base program that is executing the above given command, it terminates immediately.

the file.java program is working fine. But I don't know why getRuntime.exec() is terminating without calling it. Can there be some problem in the .jar file ?

Comment: Could you try it again using escaped backslashes: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c C:\\file.jar");`

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually I had already added the one u suggested but forgot to write it in here. I'll update it. 
Thanks